# Unknown function pick at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-84c36838170137b342ad08a194e8c35b/mongodb/manifests/params.pp:6 on node - Vagrant

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, puppet, librarian-puppet

While provision Vagrant VM  **`hashicorp/precise32`** with [puppetlabs-mongodb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb), I got an error:

> Unknown function pick at
>   /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-84c36838170137b342ad08a194e8c35b/mongodb/manifests/params.pp:6
>   on node

When I looked at line no.6 of [params.pp](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb/blob/master/manifests/params.pp), I found:

```
$service_manage = pick($mongodb::globals::mongod_service_manage, true)
```

But not sure, how to resolve it.

Any Idea how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how did you install the modules ?

This module has [dependency](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb/dependencies) on [puppetlabs/stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib). The version of stlib must be greater than 2.2 - This is where the function is defined

Install or upgrade the stdlib module and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works!. I am using `librarian-puppet` to install the puppet modules, and it's downloading dependent modules at a location other than where mongodb module is placed.